# datagridview winform update any row then corresponding column should be updated with logged user

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

SQL adapater is used to update the datagrid 
but i need to record the logged in user ...i dont know where the user will make the change in datagridview only that corresponing row the column should have logged in user.private void button()
cb = new sqlcommandbuider(adap);
adap.Update(dt);
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;>> gives logged user.

but i update the datagridview with sql adapter with a primary key in table.

any idea how to achieve this ?? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Anytime the datagrid is updated, in addition to the update, execute a separate SQL Command just to record the logged in user.

Comment: private void button()    {                                                                                 
 cb = new sqlcommandbuider(adap);                                         adap.Update(dt);   }       i have something like this to update the datagridview so i am bit confused ..

Comment: confused why?  In the same void button(), either before or after that adap.Update, build and execute a SQL command that records the logged in user.